# Cannot register user info to firebase database when creating a new user

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on a signup form and I can create a new user using firebase auth, but the part where I register informations like the name, email... in a database is not working.
On the firebase side, I created a firestore database and a realtime database, and I don't see anything on them.
I tried to use the firebase documentation but it's still not working so I am probably missing something.
Thanks for your help!

PS: I hidded my firebase config here but it's filled on my code

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js' 
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-auth.js'
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc, getDocs, collection } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-firestore.js";
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-database.js";


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "" 
  };


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
//const db = getFirestore();
const auth = getAuth(); 
const db = getDatabase();



submitData.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
    var name = document.getElementById('full_name').value
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('psw').value;
    // do verification

    // Move on with Auth
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {

      const user = userCredential.user
      alert("user created")

      //add to firebase database
      function writeUserData( name, email) {

        set(ref(db, 'users/' + userId), {
          username: name,
          email: email,
        });
      }
    })
```

Comment: "is not working" is hard to help with, so I recommend doing local debugging and sharing the results. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: When I run the code locally using a debugger, I get "Access to script at 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-firestore.js' from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-ijt is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response".